# jquery append not workign in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, internet-explorer-8, append

Im using Fullscreen Galleria Wordpress Plugin and on IE8 It does not work. Does not generate the images thumbnails.

After some searching I figure out the problem is the "append" function.
Here is the part of code with problem:

```
var size = Math.floor(box * BOX - 2 * BORDER);
  var img = fsg_json[ID][photo]['image'];
  var imgid = fsg_json[ID][photo]['id'];
  var w = fsg_json[ID][photo]['full'][1];
  var h = fsg_json[ID][photo]['full'][2];
  //console.log(size, y, x, y * BOX, x * BOX);
  var $div = $('<div style="width: ' + size + 'px; height: ' + size + 'px; top: ' + y * BOX +
              'px; left: ' + x * BOX + 'px; margin: ' + BORDER + 'px;">');
  var $a = $('<a data-postid="' + ID + '" data-imgid="' + imgid + '" href="' + img + '">');
  $($a).click(fsg_show_galleria);
  // - Find best img
  var a = ["thumbnail", "medium", "large", "full"];
  for (var s in a) {
    min = Math.min(fsg_json[ID][photo][a[s]][1],
                  fsg_json[ID][photo][a[s]][2]);
    if (min > size) {
      img = fsg_json[ID][photo][a[s]][0];
      w = fsg_json[ID][photo][a[s]][1];
      h = fsg_json[ID][photo][a[s]][2];
      break;
    }
  }
  var min = Math.min(w, h);
  var m = size / min;
  w = w * m;
  h = h * m;
  var imgx = -Math.floor((w - size) / 2.0);
  var imgy = -Math.floor((h - size) / 2.0);
  var $img = $('<img style="left: ' + imgx + 'px; top: ' + imgy + 'px;" width="' + w +
              '" height="' + h + '" src="' + img + '">');
  $a.append($img);
  $div.append($a);
  $(this).append($div);
  ++d;
```

As you can see the code uses append to build the output HTML.

Im not a javascript skilled programer so can you please help me out.
Can I use other function other then append?

Thank you.

Comment: No reason `append()` shouldn't work. How did you come to that conclusion? Are any errors thrown in dev tools console (F12) ?

Comment: Hi. The conclusion is based on HTML output generated. The HTML part that is generated whitout append is present in page source code, all the code missing from source page is exactly this part managed by append. Bye

Comment: but it could be errors thrown before `append()` gets called, or it could be css problems. `View source` does not get updated , it is only what is sent from server

Comment: There is no error thrown, and css looks fine. All working corect in IE9. What do you advise to do?

Comment: If you can send me one email where i can write you i can provide more insight

Comment: Requires using javascript debugging techniques that are not simple to explain in comments. Can inject `console.log(variable)` in various parts of code or set breakpoints to check values